# The $<$-relation on $\mathbb{Z}$ is not definable in $(\mathbb{Z}, 0, +)$

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

I am a complete newcomer to logic and I'm having trouble proving the following:

**The $<$-relation on $\mathbb{Z}$ is not definable in $(\mathbb{Z}, 0, +)$.**

Now, I know that the $<$-relation on $\mathbb{N}$ is definable in the structure $(\mathbb{N}, 0, +)$ by the formula
$$\phi(x, y) := \exists z (z \neq 0 \land z + x = y).$$
My idea was to show that if $<$ is definable in $(\mathbb{Z}, 0, +)$ then the defining formula would have to correspond to the above $\phi$ on $\mathbb{Z}^{\geq0}$ and then derive some contradiction. However, I have never done a proof of non-definability before and don't really know how one generally goes about such proofs. It is always advisable to do a proof by contradiction? And if so, is there any "standard type" of contradiction one generally looks for in such cases?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The situation is invariant under negation. It follows that you can't distinguish $\lt$ from $\gt$.

Comment: That's the elegant way of solving this!

Comment: (This is similar to the indistinguishability of $\mathrm i$ and $-\mathrm i$ in $\mathbb C$.)

Comment: (And similar to the non-definability of left and right.)

Comment: I don't think I understand. Do you mean if the formula $\psi$ defines $<$ on $(\mathbb{Z}, 0, +)$ then we have for all $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}: \psi(x,y) \iff x < y \iff -y < -x \iff \psi(-y, -x)$? What does this imply, how do I go on?

Comment: @TomBombadil: (Nice name, by the way :-) No, I mean that because of the symmetry of the situation there can be no formula that holds for $\lt$ but not for $\gt$, much like there can be no equation in $(\mathbb C,0,1,+,\cdot)$ that holds for $\mathrm i$ but not for $-\mathrm i$. You have nothing in $(\mathbb Z,0,+)$ that distinguishes between the two. Perhaps this is easier to see if you first try defining $1$ -- this is impossible for analogous reasons, because you can't distinguish it from $-1$.

Comment: @TomBombadil: More formally, $(-a)+(-b)=-(a+b)$, so negation doesn't change the truth value of any sentences that you can write down in $(\mathbb Z,0,+)$. If this is not immediately clear, perhaps write down some sentences and check that for any valuation that satisfies them, the valuation you get by negating all values also satisfies them. Thus for any valuation that satisfies a sentence that's meant to define $\lt$, the negated valuation also satisfies the sentence -- but negation turns $\lt$ into $\gt$, so the sentence would also have to define $\gt$, a different relation.

Comment: I think now I understand: You're looking at the automorphism of the structure $(\mathbb{Z}, 0, +)$ that sends each number to its negative and then you're basically just applying the invariance theorem (for which you assume there is a formula $\phi$ that defines $<$ on $(\mathbb{Z}, 0, +)$). And this leads to the indistinguishability of $<$ and $>$.

Comment: @TomBombadil: I don't know the name "invariance theorem", but that sounds like it could be a rigorous formalization of the argument. Certainly the part about the automorphism is right.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to check that $h:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ via $x\mapsto -x$ is an automorphism and $\mathbb{Z}^+$, the set of positive integers, is not closed under this automorphism. Hence $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is not definable in $(\mathbb{Z},0,+)$. Note that **the definability of $<$-relation is the same as $\mathbb{Z}^+$.**

Comment: Is there a good reason to post what is essentially the accepted answer, with not much more detail to it, on something which is about two years old?